# Is it possible reply post comments with LinkedIn v1 API (spring social)?

Tags: rest, api, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

I use spring social linkedin and as I know if I want to comment to post use this:

```
new LinkedInTemplate(apiToken).networkUpdateOperations().commentOnNetworkUpdate(updateKey, comment);
```

updateKey format: "UPDATE-cxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", where first is pageId, second part is postId.
And this works for me.

**But how reply post comments? Is it possible at all?**

I know the comment id, eg: 6498049894299829852

But if I have added this to commentOnNetworkUpdate as updateKey then I have got bad request error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do this with the V1 api, it only is available with the V2 api.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/network-update-social-actions#create-delete